# error in runninng application in visual studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

```
ERROR: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  
This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

I am running an application in `Visual Studio 12` and first I installed `Oracle 11g 64 bit` on `Windows 7 64bit` after than it was showing the same error Attempt to load.

Then I installed `SQL developer` 32 bit mode using `jdk` 32 bit then my report mailers that is also developed in the same application started working but my application that I used to run on local host is not accepting my credentials and displaying the same error when checking data connection in server explorer.

I tried installing both the 32 bit and 64 bit and changing configuration manager mode to everything(cpu , 64 bit , 32 bit ).

Comment: SQL Developer runs on Java with JDBC. It should not interfere with any .NET assembly.

Comment: Did you follow this [instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)? Check carefully your environment settings (`PATH`, `ORACLE_HOME`), resp. Registry settings.

Comment: ya i installed both the oracle but in different directories and i am trying to do whatever that is written in the first answer #the link but as my directories are different so not able to make the  symbolic links as i installed sql 32 bit in some app folder d drive and 64 bit in e drive . i am unbale to move the app folder to c drive as described there .

Comment: ya i implemented this thing properly , but still problem not solved o.O

Comment: The symbolic links are the most important items when you do the installation. Why are you not able to create them?